# Convert from TypeReference<E> to Class<E> without casting (Java)

Tags: java, generics, casting, jackson

I want to go from a `TypeReference<E>` object to a `Class<E>` object in Java, *without* using casting. I require the usage of `TypeReference` because of the way my code uses **Jackson** and I need `Class` object because I want to use it to infer a type into one of my other Generic Classes in my app.

I know that `TypeReference.getType()` will return a [java.lang.reflect.Type](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/Type.html) object. Basically, if I can find out a way to use code without casting to get from `Type` to `Class`, then I have figured out my problem.

**Javadoc References:**

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html
- http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.9.4/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/type/TypeReference.html

Comment: `Type` is an interface, not an object, whereas `Class` is a subclass of `Object`.

Comment: I know that. But my question was how to go from `TypeReference` to `Class`. In only mentioned about the `Type` interface in case it assist someone solving the problem.

Comment: Isn't `Type` representing a type without any classloader information? So if it points to class `Foo`, it could mean any of the actual `Foo` classes loaded by different classloaders?

Comment: `TypeReference.getClass()` will give you the `Class`, but you can't really go from a `Type` to a `Class`.

Comment: @doublesharp: `TypeReference.getClass()` will return the class object representing `TypeReference`, not representing the generic type.

Comment: But technically `Class` implements the `Type` interface, so a simple cast should do the job.

Comment: @ecbrodie You need to get the parameterized `Type` of `TypeReference`?

Comment: @biziclop: Doing so will give me the warning: "Class is a raw type. References to generic type Class<T> should be parameterized"

Comment: @ecbrodie Well, you can cast it to `Class<?>` then. Or you can just ignore the warning.

Comment: This might be useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/restrictions.html#createObjects

Comment: It was. I now have warning-free code. I'm relying more on wildcards (as in `MyObjectType<?>` instead of `MyObjectType<E>`). Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can not cast it: this is very basic Java question -- TypeReference and Class do not derive from same base class so it is against language definition.

But if I guess correctly what you trying to achieve, you can convert raw (type-erased) class by using `JavaType`:

```
JavaType type = mapper.getTypeFactory().constructType(ref);
Class<?> cls = type.getRawClass();
```

You can construct `JavaType` out of `TypeReference`, `Class`, or even just basic JDK `Type`.

Comment: Which package/jar is `JavaType` from?

Comment: Nevermind...it is from Jackson. However, I am not sure what class type your `mapper` object is. It isn't `ObjectMapper`; I can't find an `ObjectMaper.getTypeFactory()` method. Instead, my solution that I derive from your is `TypeFactory.defaultInstance().constructType(typeReference).getRawClass()`. Thanks.

Comment: `ObjectMapper` has `getTypeFactory()` (see http://fasterxml.github.com/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.1.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html) but maybe older versions did not expose it. You can use defaultInstance if so.

Comment: Hold on a sec...that is Jackson by *FasterXML*, not *Codehaus*. Which version of Jackson is the official one?

Comment: Jackson moved from Codehaus repository to GitHub for 2.x. So Codehaus has old (1.9), github has new. And new has Java package under `com.fasterxml`. Both are official, just different Java packages.

Answer (score 4):

I don't see any solution without casting. However, here is a solution with kind of generic casting. Maybe this can help, too:

```
public class Converter {
    public static <T> Class<T> convert(TypeReference<T> ref) {
        return (Class<T>)((ParameterizedType) ref.getType()).getRawType();
    }
}
```

However this is a framework method. The signature is fully type save and it converts to a class containing all the 'super type token' information Neal Gafter mentions in his [blog entry](http://gafter.blogspot.de/2006/12/super-type-tokens.html) that's delivered the idea of TypeReference. By that it keeps your business code clean and type save.

Usage would then (Here you can't see the cast...;-):

```
Class<List<String>> typ = Converter.convert(new TypeReference<List<String>>() {});
System.out.println(typ);
```

With output (Of course the instance is type ereased even though the code shows the String...):

```
interface java.util.List
```